# Returning column names as cell values in R

Tags: r

For this data frame:

```
Indicator <- c('A',NA, 'I', NA)
A<- c('1',NA,NA,NA)

I<- c(NA,'0','0',NA)

E<- c(NA,NA,NA,'0')

data.frame(Indicator,A,I,E)
```

I want to look down the Indicator column; if the value is NA I want to look across to the other columns and where there is a non-missing value I want to return the column name as an Indicator value. So in this case the outcome should look like this:

```
Indicator <- c('A','I','I','E')


data.frame(Indicator,A,I,E)
```

Comment: Generally R uses `NA` as a missing value (notice no quotes). Your sample data has strings `"NA"` which are not special missing values in R. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Have removed the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = data.frame(Indicator,A,I,E)
cols = c("A", "I", "E")
data$Indicator = ifelse(
  is.na(data$Indicator), 
  cols[max.col(!is.na(data[cols]), ties.method = "first")],
  data$Indicator
)
data
#   Indicator    A    I    E
# 1         A    1 <NA> <NA>
# 2         I <NA>    0 <NA>
# 3         I <NA>    0 <NA>
# 4         E <NA> <NA>    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` appraoch:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# 1. as data frame
df %>%  
  mutate(across(A:E, ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(Indicator, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  select(Indicator, everything())

 Indicator    A    I    E
1         A    1 <NA> <NA>
2         I <NA>    0 <NA>
3         I <NA>    0 <NA>
4         E <NA> <NA>    0

# 2. as vector
Indicator <- df %>%  
  mutate(across(A:E, ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  pull(New_Col)

[1] "A" "I" "I" "E"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `tidyverse` solution. I think pivoting longer then back again is a little more straight-forward than the `mutate(across())` pattern in this case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Indicator, A, I, E)

df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(A:E) |> 
  mutate(
    Indicator = if_else(is.na(Indicator), name[!is.na(value)], Indicator), 
    .by = id
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider() |> 
  select(!id)
```